# Initial Page Loading taking time in Angular2

Tags: angular

I need your idea/suggestion to reduce page loading in Angular 2 for my application.

Page Rendering is taking time in initial load in Angular2.page loading time taking 4 to 6 sec for rendering UI elements in every page load.

Our requirement will be load the page with in 2 seconds

I am trying to open a another page from parent page. but UI rendering taking time in initial load. its taking 4 to 6 sec for rendering UI element for every refresh.
Script execution for creating UI element is taking time in build copy 
we are using angular 2.0.1 and for build we are using gulp with systemjs build file

Angular version: 2.0.X we are using latest version (Angular,Node ,Npm,Typescripts)
Please share your ideas & suggestion for reducing loading time in Angular 2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

To load the page faster,lazy load the modules in your project.

See more about how to lazy load in angular 2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#lazy-load

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. let me check the link and revert back if the issue still exists